# Codeigniter - uri segment not returning anything

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I have a view which encrypts the current `pid` from database and when a 'save' button is clicked, it will redirect to the other controller.

My URL is encrypted. So, the 3rd segment in my URL is the pid, encrypted. So my URL will be:

```
 http://localhost/profile/edit_entry/3YnwZhh5hLiYEB2ICaPUgZs.6Ydz8C1mbyiGoJnTcw34Ejuy0sgeIasI3C2fVxoZca4SgZ9mjKsqmX.l8otGrw--
```

But When I decode it and try to echo it, it won't echo anything.

My controller:

```
$pid = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $pid = $this->encrypt->decode($pid);

    echo "$pid";
```

Nothing happens. Any idea?

Comment: as an alternative, try to get it in the method as an argument

Comment: @Ghost What do you mean? Can you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: instead of using segments, haven't you tried this http://pastebin.com/jvWzQbb9

Comment: Still not working ;(

Comment: what do you get when you `echo $this->uri->segment(3);`?? Also, are you loading the encrypt class at all (autoload.php or `$this->load->library('encrypt');`)?

Comment: Yes, It's autoloaded. And I have fixed the issue. Thanks ;)

Comment: If you could explain the answer then others who might have the same problem could find this and figure it out too ... Please? ;)

Comment: which one is your controller name profile or edit_entry ?

Comment: can you please specify the version of Codeigniter you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i've tested and working:

First need to be loaded the Library 'encrypt' this can be loaded on autoload.php or just call the Library on your controller:

As i see, first of all you have created an encrypted id to no show the real id in the url, and you need to decrypt to get the id on post/edit/etc.

so, we will create a method Edit.

```
public function Edit($id){

            $this->load->library('encrypt');
            $pid = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $pid = $this->encrypt->decode($pid);

            var_dump($pid);
}
```

Comment: better.. thanks for explaining.. unfortunately, i believe Taylor has found his answer and is not following up at all.. shame on him.